# How can Popen() use same environment as Pycharm using Anaconda python?

Tags: python, pycharm, popen

I am trying to call a python script B.py inside A.py by using a line like:

```py
proc=subprocess.Popen('python3 /B.py')
```

The PyCharm gives an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'`. However B.py is bug free to run itself when I click `'Run B.py'` in PyCharm directly.

The question is how do I force `Popen()` run a script in the same environment as when directly run the script from PyCharm?

To be more specific:

1. B.py can be run successfully in Pycharm and its anaconda python 3.7 environment.
2. A.py is running in Pycharm under same environment as 1 mentioned.

--------------------------new attempts--------------------

In Pycharm Preferences page, I found the Interpreter Path is `/Users/hanchennan/opt/anaconda3/python.app/Contents/MacOS/python`

So I tried this

```py
proc = subprocess.Popen("python3 /Users/hanchennan/PycharmProjects/curve/B.py",
                         shell=True, env={'PATH':'/Users/hanchennan/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7'})
```

Now the error becomes `/bin/sh: python3: command not found`, which remains same for python3/python37.

This is all I have tried, guys please help me out!

-----------------------Solved--------------------

Problem solved! The right path should be

`/Users/hanchennan/opt/anaconda3/bin`